# The meaning of "on nya répond"?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, oral

Recently, I watched a video on 1jour1actu[1]. In the end of the video, I heard "Tu poses des questions, on nya(?) répond."

Did I heard that correctly? What is the meaning of it?

[1] http://www.1jour1actu.com/info-animee/pourquoi-mange-t-on-epice-dans-certains-pays/

Comment: It's `on y répond`: _"Tu poses des questions, on y répond"_ -> _"You're asking questions and we answer them"_

Comment: @Andreas actually he said "Tu **te** poses des questions ? **Nous,** on y répond "

Comment: @PaulLemarchand You're right. I've probably focused too much on `on y répond` and missed/ignored the rest of the sentence... :|

Comment: That's a good hearing. Can you post your answer? @PaulLemarchand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speaker said "***Tu te poses des questions ? Nous, on y répond !***", 
which could be translated as : "*You're asking yourselves questions ? We answer them !*"

Let's divide the sentences :

- ***Tu te poses des questions ?*** (You're asking yourselves questions ?)

Here, the formal way of saying it would be "*Te poses-tu des questions ?*" (Are you asking yourselves questions ?), but in spoken language you will probably never hear this form (even with my boss or my teachers it would be too formal !). 
If you want to be formal, consider using "*Vous vous posez des questions ?"*)

Note that if you didn't hear the `te`, it's because he didn't pronounce the `e`, which is pretty common in spoken language (literally : *tu t'poses des questions ?*)

- ***Nous, on y répond !*** (We answer them !)

The speaker could have simply said "*On y répond*", but this would have been too neutral. "*Nous,*" adds some empathy to the sentence (once again pretty common thing in spoken language !)

For example : *On parle français* (neutral) --> *Nous, on parle français* (emphatic)

Comment: So, the sound "ou" is actually «nous» ? Also, in «tu t'poses», is it read as /tut pose/ ?

Comment: I can distinctly hear "nous", maybe it requires some training. I would say it really is /tu tpose/ as the t and the p are really stuck together.

Comment: To be more exact with the IPA, « Tu te poses des questions ? » here is / **tytpoz**dekɛstjɔ̃/, and a slow, careful pronunciation would begin /tyt**ə**poz/.